# Is there any way to directly run our ruby codes from puppet console?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am new to both Ruby Language and Puppet. I want to run a ruby code which is a converted form of a cURL, from my puppet console.

I am putting the cURL and the converted ruby below.

```
curl -k -u stg_admin:password -sS -X POST https://www.something.com
```

As you can see, this is a very basic cURL, and the converted ruby code is-

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'openssl'

uri = URI.parse("https://www.something.com")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.basic_auth("stg_admin", "password")

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
  verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

# response.code
# response.body
```

I know how to exec cURL directly in my puppet class, but my question is "is there any way to **call my ruby code directly** in puppet's init.pp?"
I'll be greatfull for any suggestion.

Comment: From the console: no. From the `init.pp`: yes. You can use a `file` resource to transfer it and then `exec` to execute it locally. Does that sound like what you are trying to achieve? I want to point out though that all of this sounds rather off from best practices.

Comment: Yes, that is something I want to achieve. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ok, then the thing is there are already SO answers on how to deploy and execute a script with Puppet like this. I would check those out to see what fits you best.

Comment: @MattSchuchard , another thing I will like to share. I have tried to transfer the file and `exec` it in my module,but I was getting an error message saying **`"Failed to apply catalog: parameter path failed on File['file_path']:file path must be fully qualified, not 'the_fully_qualified_path_I_had_given"`**

Comment: You should probably post some sample code in a new question.

Comment: Ok, I will post another question with sample codes. @MattSchuchard